# Using Webpack and Django settings

Tags: django, webpack

I try to use `Django-webpack-loader` with `Django` and `VueJs` but I am not able to use correct settings with my complex project setup to load `webpack bundle`. My project layout is

```
    Endofyogavidya
    --dist/bundle.js
    manage.py
    webpack.config.js
    --Yogavidya
    ----apps
    ----static
    --------main.js
    --------App.Vue
    ----templates
    ----settings
    ------base.py
    ------development.py
```

In my settings.py

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/public/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "dist"),
)

WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'CACHE': not DEBUG,
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': '',
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'webpack-stats.json'),
        'POLL_INTERVAL': 0.1,
        'TIMEOUT': None,
        'IGNORE': ['.+\.hot-update.js', '.+\.map']
    }
}
```

My index.html is not working because with these settings django tries collect my assets to `'/home/ytsejam/public_html/endofyogavidya/yogavidya/settings/dist'`. How can I adjust my folder settings correctly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice tut on this. Follow the below link

https://medium.com/labcodes/configuring-django-with-react-4c599d1eae63

It is for ReactJS but hope you can relate it to the framework you are using.